# Why does ansible not work with vmware module?

Tags: ansible, vmware

Ansible 2.9.10
Vcentre 6.7

I am quite confused by this issue that has suddenly appeared for me.

This all worked perfectly fine the last time I ran it which was a few weeks ago, all of a sudden it has completely stopped working and I have no idea whats wrong.

I have a playbook that simpy Powers off a VM guest using ansible

```
- hosts: all

  tasks:
- name: Power off VM
          vmware_guest_powerstate:
            hostname: "{{ vcenter_hostname }}"
            username: "{{ vcenter_username }}"
            password: "{{ vcenter_password }}"
            name: "{{ guest_name | default(inventory_hostname) }}"
            state: shutdown-guest
            state_change_timeout: 600
            validate_certs: False
          delegate_to: localhost
```

Now, whenever I run the playbook I get error below:

ansible-playbook -i hosts poweroff.yml -l myserverA.mydomain.com

```
TASK [Power off VM] ***********************************************************************************************************************
fatal: [myserverA.mydomain.com]: UNREACHABLE! => {"changed": false, "msg": "Failed to connect to the host via ssh: Permission denied (publickey,gssapi-keyex,gssapi-with-mic,password).", "unreachable": true}
```

I have tested various other vmware modules that use to work too such as taking snapshots and none of them work either. Also test against a bunch of different servers which all produce the same error.

What is confusing about that error is its stating "ssh" issue, but I thought Ansible node connects to vcentre via API so port 443, not using ssh?

I have confirmed Ansible node can ssh into the server myserverA.mydomain.com fine and also can ping vcentre host and also telnet to port 443 and 22.

Googling did not find anyone that had same issue as me.

Please anyone have any ideas?

Comment: Do you need `hosts: all` when all you want is to run the task on localhost (using `delegate_to`)?

Comment: That is more of a snippit of my playbook, there are various other tasks that happen after powering off the VM too which does not use delegate_to.

Comment: you mean only vmware modules are not working? Did you check with ping or command modules?

Answer (score 0):

The cause of the ssh error is `gather_facts` enabled.
When `gather_facts` enabled, Ansible connects to `inventory_hostname`.
The solution to this thing is `gather_facts` to disable.
Here's the playbook for `gather_facts` disable.

```yaml
- hosts: all
  gather_facts: false

  tasks:
    - name: Power off VM
      vmware_guest_powerstate:
        hostname: "{{ vcenter_hostname }}"
        username: "{{ vcenter_username }}"
        password: "{{ vcenter_password }}"
        validate_certs: no
        name: "{{ guest_name | default(inventory_hostname) }}"
        state: shutdown-guest
        state_change_timeout: 600
        validate_certs: False
      delegate_to: localhost
```

Answer (score 0):

Take a look on the below example provided from plugin documentation.

```
- name: Set the state of a virtual machine to poweron using MoID
  community.vmware.vmware_guest_powerstate:
    hostname: "{{ vcenter_hostname }}"
    username: "{{ vcenter_username }}"
    password: "{{ vcenter_password }}"
    folder: "/{{ datacenter_name }}/vm/my_folder"
    moid: vm-42
    state: powered-on
  delegate_to: localhost
  register: deploy
```

You should connect to your vcenter server instead of all hosts. You can add your credentials on a vault.

```
vars_files:
    - secrets.yml
    - other.yml
```

**secrets.yml**

```
vcenter_username : administrator@vsphere.local
vcenter_password : password
vcenter_hostname : vcenter.hostname
```

and run the playbook using the vault command

```
ansible-playbook playbook.yml --ask-vault-pass
```

*If it still fails, try also to enstablish an ssh connection between your host where vcenter is installed and ansible server. (ssh keys installation)*